# Why tfx.components.FnArgs does not have an "epochs" attribute?

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

`tfx.components.FnArgs` is the way to pass values to the `run_fn` function which will in turn train the model in Tensorflow Extended pipeline.

Looking at the [tfx.components.FnArgs' documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/api_docs/python/tfx/v1/components/FnArgs), I cannot help but wonder why there's no attribute for the number of epochs to run the training loop (perhaps the most important attribute in training). Is this an oversight or am I supposed to control the number of epochs differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `epochs` attribute in `custom_config` dict as shown in [example notebook](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/recommenders#training_the_model).

Example code:

```
trainer = tfx.components.Trainer(
    module_file=os.path.abspath(_trainer_module_file),
    examples=ratings_transform.outputs['transformed_examples'],
    transform_graph=ratings_transform.outputs['transform_graph'],
    schema=ratings_transform.outputs['post_transform_schema'],
    train_args=tfx.proto.TrainArgs(num_steps=500),
    eval_args=tfx.proto.EvalArgs(num_steps=10),
    custom_config={
        'epochs':5,
        'movies':movies_transform.outputs['transformed_examples'],
        'movie_schema':movies_transform.outputs['post_transform_schema'],
        'ratings':ratings_transform.outputs['transformed_examples'],
        'ratings_schema':ratings_transform.outputs['post_transform_schema']
        })

context.run(trainer, enable_cache=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also do something like the below with `train_args` and `eval_args`, which may be a more direct solution:

```
trainer = Trainer(                                                              
    module_file=trainer_file,                                                   
    examples=transform.outputs['transformed_examples'],                         
    transform_graph = transform.outputs['transform_graph'],                     
    schema=transform.outputs['post_transform_schema'],                          
    hyperparameters = tuner.outputs['best_hyperparameters'],                    
    train_args=proto.TrainArgs(splits=['train'], num_steps=50),                 
    eval_args=proto.EvalArgs(splits=['eval'], num_steps=5))
```